# better EdmGen2?

Tags: linq, ado.net, linq-to-entities, edmx

I'm using the microsoft EdmGen2 to generate my edmx file from my database. The tool works great, but there is one things missing - it doesn't support function. Is there a way to map all the stored procedures to be functions?

Also, if i'm editing it manually, the next time im running this tool, i'm losing all those changes.

my question:

is there any better tool that can help me to do this + the functions/stored proc mapping

thanks